# JavaScript-Not able to Implement multiple Or in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am  a JavaScript newbie trying to Implement an If statement with multiple "OR" conditions

I have no Issues comparing two Items, but when I do three, like this

```
if(dealStage=="Stage1" ||dealStage=="Stage2"||dealStage=="Stage3"){}
```

The condition doesn't get satisfied even when the Deal Stage is set to Stage3.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet.

Comment: This should work as it is, so please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the Issue was. The dealStage which I thought was set to "Stage3" was actually set to this value "dc937904-cc58-4b8c-b7a9-aa2f7f11609d" and hence it was not satisfying the condition.

So, before the Final If condition, I added another If condition that goes something like this,

if(dealStage=="dc937904-cc58-4b8c-b7a9-aa2f7f11609d"){dealStage="Stage3"} and it now works.

Thanks @Andreas for confirming that the If Condition works.